# How can I perform a simutaneous estimation of binary and multinomial models in STATA?

Tags: econometrics, stata

In particular, I need to estimate at the same time the choice between enrolling at University or not and, if enrolling, which field the individual will choose.
In order to so I would need a binary model for the first choice and a multinomial for the second one.
I tried to use a for loop as found online to run the estimation I need but STATA only peforms single regressions for each variable at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there is such an econometric technique as you describe. 
The existance of a Stata command is a second-order problem. What estimator are you thinking of? What method do you want to use? Once that is clarified, we can think about how to code it.

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way? Why not do a multinomial logit and then have the baseline category be "don't enroll" and then the other choices are "enroll in medicine", "enroll in economics", "enroll in math", and so on.